# Exclusion Script for Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ampscript, exclusion-script

I need exclusion script for Trigger send definition to exclude records on type of activity.

This is sample table that is sendable: [**Sample_Customeractivity_table**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PbF06VXDHLuBv5xqOiJEEqzTStJlqW1kcifTY_SETsc/edit?usp=sharing)

I have another trigger DE `trigger_customeractivity_table` where i am saving the trigger records.

i have 10 types of emails for 10 types of "typecode",

In 1st script - i want exclude all type2 to type10

In 2nd script - i want exclude all type1 and type3 to type10

In 3rd script - i want exclude all type1 and type2 and type4 to type10

In 4th ...

etc

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
Not Empty(Lookup("cus_activity","EmailAddress","typecode","type1‌​") OR 
Not Empty(Lookup("cus_activity","EmailAddress","typecode","type2‌​") OR 
Not Empty(Lookup("cus_activity","EmailAddress","typecode","type3‌​")
```

Comment: Have you attempted to write the AMPScript for it?  If so, please update your question with what you've got so far.  If not, please try it first.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs i tried with this script 
 ` Not Empty(Lookup("cus_activity","EmailAddress","typecode","type1") OR Not Empty(Lookup("cus_activity","EmailAddress","typecode","type2") OR Not Empty(Lookup("cus_activity","EmailAddress","typecode","type3") `  but no success.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `empty()` to check `lookup()` results.  The [**Lookup()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm) function returns a *rowset*.

Your best bet would be to use the [**rowcount()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/rowcount.htm) function.

Also, I'm assuming that your `typecode` values are in your send context, so you'd either reference them without quotes or using the [**AttributeValue()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attributevalue.htm) function.

Will work, but not recommended:

```
rowcount(Lookup("cus_activity","EmailAddress","typecode", type1) > 0 OR
rowcount(Lookup("cus_activity","EmailAddress","typecode", type2) > 0 OR
rowcount(Lookup("cus_activity","EmailAddress","typecode", type3) > 0
```

This is better:

```
rowcount(Lookup("cus_activity","EmailAddress","typecode", AttributeValue("type1‌​")) > 0 OR
rowcount(Lookup("cus_activity","EmailAddress","typecode", AttributeValue("type2​")) > 0 OR
rowcount(Lookup("cus_activity","EmailAddress","typecode", AttributeValue("type3​")) > 0
```